# access objects in pyspark user-defined function from outer scope, avoid PicklingError: Could not serialize object

Tags: python, apache-spark, serialization, pyspark, user-defined-functions

How do I avoid initializing a class within a `pyspark` user-defined function?  Here is an example.

Creating a `spark` session and DataFrame representing four latitudes and longitudes.

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled', 'true')
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

sdf = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({
    'lat': [37, 42, 35, -22],
    'lng': [-113, -107, 127, 34]}))
```

Here is the Spark DataFrame

```
+---+----+
|lat| lng|
+---+----+
| 37|-113|
| 42|-107|
| 35| 127|
|-22|  34|
+---+----+
```

Enriching the DataFrame with a timezone string at each latitude / longitude via the `timezonefinder` package.  **Code below runs without errors**

```
from typing import Iterator
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder

def func(iterator: Iterator[pd.DataFrame]) -> Iterator[pd.DataFrame]:
    for dx in iterator:
        tzf = TimezoneFinder()
        dx['timezone'] = [tzf.timezone_at(lng=a, lat=b) for a, b in zip(dx['lng'], dx['lat'])]
        yield dx
pdf = sdf.mapInPandas(func, schema='lat double, lng double, timezone string').toPandas()
```

The above code runs without errors and creates the pandas DataFrame below.  The issue is the `TimezoneFinder` class is initialized within the user-defined function which creates a bottleneck

```
In [4]: pdf
Out[4]:
    lat    lng         timezone
0  37.0 -113.0  America/Phoenix
1  42.0 -107.0   America/Denver
2  35.0  127.0       Asia/Seoul
3 -22.0   34.0    Africa/Maputo
```

The question is how to get this code to run more like below, where the `TimezoneFinder` class is initialized once and outside of the user-defined function.  As is, the code below generates this error `PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.BufferedReader' object`

```
def func(iterator: Iterator[pd.DataFrame]) -> Iterator[pd.DataFrame]:
    for dx in iterator:
        dx['timezone'] = [tzf.timezone_at(lng=a, lat=b) for a, b in zip(dx['lng'], dx['lat'])]
        yield dx
tzf = TimezoneFinder()
pdf = sdf.mapInPandas(func, schema='lat double, lng double, timezone string').toPandas()
```

UPDATE - Also tried to use `functools.partial` and an outer function but still received same error.  That is, this approach does not work:

```
def outer(iterator, tzf):
    def func(iterator: Iterator[pd.DataFrame]) -> Iterator[pd.DataFrame]:
        for dx in iterator:
            dx['timezone'] = [tzf.timezone_at(lng=a, lat=b) for a, b in zip(dx['lng'], dx['lat'])]
            yield dx
    return func(iterator)
tzf = TimezoneFinder()
outer = partial(outer, tzf=tzf)
pdf = sdf.mapInPandas(outer, schema='lat double, lng double, timezone string').toPandas()
```

Comment: Show the stack trace.

Comment: "The issue is the `TimezoneFinder` class is initialized within the user-defined function which creates a bottleneck" What bottleneck is that?

Comment: ```TimezoneFinder``` is a proxy for any object that needs instantiation, eg loading a reference data file.  The goal is to create the object once then pass the instantiated object to workers for distributed processing.  If the object takes some time to create there will be a bottleneck.

Comment: You cannot pickle open file objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need a cached instance of the object on every worker.
You could do that as follows

```
instance = [None]

def func(iterator: Iterator[pd.DataFrame]) -> Iterator[pd.DataFrame]:
    if instance[0] is None:
        instance[0] = TimezoneFinder()
    tzf = instance[0]
    for dx in iterator:
        dx['timezone'] = [tzf.timezone_at(lng=a, lat=b) for a, b in zip(dx['lng'], dx['lat'])]
        yield dx
```

Note that for this to work, your function would be defined within a module, to give the instance cache somewhere to live. Else you would have to hang it off some builtin module, e.g., `os.instance = []`.

Comment: Ok, accepted the answer.  The key idea is to put the function in a **separate** module and to define ```TimezoneFinder``` (or any other instance) within ```func``` and before the loop over ```iterator``` (as in your answer) .  I suppose a built-in module (```os```) could be used for that purpose but not recommended.  Did some experiments with / without the ```instance``` object and ```if``` statement in your answer, and did not find that piece necessary.

Comment: It would only be necessary if this code were executed dynamically, e.g., in a notebook cell rather than a module.